# Rails 5: grouped_collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following `grouped_collection_select` where the categories and subcategories show on a form. Currently the subcategories are selectable and not the categories. I want it to be the other way around... the categories to be selectable and subcategories not to be selectable. How can I implement this?

```
<%= form.grouped_collection_select :category_id, Category.roots.order(:name), :children, :name, :id, :name, {:include_blank => true}, {class: "", :multiple => true } %>
```

[image]

Comment: you want to select "accessories"? this is not possible. you need to find JS library which can do something like this.

Comment: Yes that is correct @Igor Kasyanchuk, I want to be able to select accessories. I know that I could just use a `collection select` with all the categories, but I would like to show the subcategories also below like the above pic. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: maybe something like https://dowjones.github.io/react-dropdown-tree-select/#/story/basic-no-extra-styles and see other demos

Comment: Thanks @ Igor Kasyanchuk, I will try it out and I will let u know how it work out.